# Ставится ли запятая перед деепричастием?

Tags: деепричастия

В предложении: «Записаться на получение данной услуги можно воспользовавшись сервисом...» Не ставить запятую? Подходит ли это правило сюда: «Если деепричастия непосредственно примыкают к глаголу и имеют значение образа действия, запятая не ставится».Записаться на получение услуги можно как?...Воспользовавшись сервисом... Без запятой?

Answer (score 1):

Похожие примеры Розенталя с запятой:
*Понять это произведение можно, только учитывая условия его создания.

Выучить иностранный язык можно, лишь постоянно занимаясь им.*

Сравнить:
*Записался, воспользовавшись сервисом.* || Где здесь образ действия? Он должен при любых формах глагола сохраняться. Здесь имеют место два разные действия: записался и воспользовался.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, нужна: да, такое правило есть, но при нём нет примера с безличным предложением.